Using Function for Contours
Is this a bug in Contours or I am using the function incorrectly?
In the second code the function works well but in the third code it fails.
The first and third images should be the same.
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> None,
  Contours -> Table[{k, Red}, {k, -4, 4, 1}]]

ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> None,
  Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Table[k, {k, min, max, 1}]]]

ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> None,
  Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Table[{k, Red}, {k, min, max, 1}]]]




Maybe still not implemented. ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> None,   Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Table[k, {k, min, max, 1}]],   ContourStyle -> {Red, Cyan, Red}]

I think it could be a bug. You should report to WR.  Can reproduce in 14.1 on Win 10.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

{zmin, zmax} = #[{x^2 - y^2, -2 <= x <= 2, -2 <= y <= 2}, {x, y}] & /@
  {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {-4, 4} *)

zdelta = 1;

ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> Table[
   {k, {Thick, ColorData["Rainbow"][(k - zmin)/(zmax - zmin)]}},
   {k, zmin, zmax, zdelta}],
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-4, 4}},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 360],
 MaxRecursion -> 4]


When using Function with Contours option also use ContourStyle option
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 ContourShading -> None,
 Contours -> Function[{min, max}, Table[k, {k, min, max, 1}]],
 ContourStyle ->
  ({Thick, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[#, {zmin, zmax}]]} & /@
    Subdivide[zmin, zmax, 8]),
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-4, 4}},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 360],
 MaxRecursion -> 4]



This does not answer the question. I know how to color contours by other means (like without function or with restricted function and with ContourStyle). The point is to do it with function in option Contours only and to judge whether it is a bug or not.
